# Looking for a huge circuit compilation

Tags: design, books

I have noticed that during my circuit design i always end up finding around the net  better ways to improve my designs pic related its an example,

Its a fuse blown indicator that gets improved by using a mosfet, in the left  the led only turns on when there is a load connected and the fuse is blown, but in the right circuit (mosfet one) the led turns on whenever the fuse blows even if there is no load

[image]

Even after reading the theory i didnt understand how mosfets worked until i saw this working live

I have been wondering where can i find a huge compilation like this, im thinking about a huge compilation of circuit designs that can be implemented right away, some kind of bible that has a brief explanation of all kinds of configurations for OP amps, all kinds of circuit schemmatics for several types of transistors, in short im looking for a circuit compilation

does this book or something similar exist?

Comment: Look for vendor application notes. TI in particular has a huge library including all of their acquisitions' application notes, most notably those from National Semiconductor.

Comment: http://www.discovercircuits.com/list.htm  contains a large collection of schematic snippets.

Answer (score 3):

I would get a copy of The Art of Electronics.  It's considered by many as the "bible" of electronics design.  It's an old book but to this day it's a really good reference.

Answer (score 1):

There use to be all these electronics "cookbooks" you can order them cheap on line.
Opamp cookbook
Cmos Cookbook
TTL cookbook
IC timer cookbook
(I'm trying to think of others..)

Comment: TV Typewriter Cookbook (Don Lancaster), IC Array Cookbook, IC Converter Cookbook (both by Walt Jung). RTL, TTL and CMOS Cookbooks, Cheap Video Cookbook and Son of Cheap Video are by Don Lancaster. I have them all on a shelf beside me.

Comment: @JohnHonniball, I guess I'm not suppose to grin and say thanks, without adding something.  Don L. passes through the usernet newsgroup sci.elec.design, much looser and ruder than here.